# Why am I unable to access $stateParams on controller ng-init?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using a controller in the body tag to instantiate some variables that are used through the application, namely the language that will be used in the application (based on the url param).

```
<!--index.html-->
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <section ui-view></section>
</body>
```

In the init() function I try to read the "lan" param from the url using $stateParams but it's still undefined:

```
/*AppCtrl*/
$scope.init = function () {
    console.log($stateParams); // prints Object {lan: "en"}
    console.log($stateParams.lan); // prints undefined
    $timeout(function () {console.log($stateParams.lan);}, 500); //prints "en"
}
```

It's odd because I can see it print $stateParams with the .lan property I can't access it.

Also I configured the $stateProvider like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        url: '/{lan:(?:pt|en)}',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
        params: { lan: { value: 'pt' } },
    })
    .state('home', {
        parent: 'root',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/front/main/views/front-main.client.view.html'
    });
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way is to remove the ng-controller from here

```
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-init="init()">
```

and move it to state

```
.state('root', {
    url: '/{lan:(?:pt|en)}',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    params: { lan: { value: 'pt' } },
    controller:'AppCtrl'
})
```

In general.. states' `views` and their `controllers` are about *UI-Router* world... and not AngularJS ng-controller